# Amazon S3 multipart upload through Flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

We're working on a flutter app where we want to upload single large files (100-150 MBs) directly to S3. The upload is too slow for our use case even though we're sending `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`. We've looked through [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html) and found out that we should be using [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html#java).

Now the problem is doesn't `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` ensure that the file will be uploaded in chunks? If it doesn't, how can we break the file into parts at frontend using flutter and upload all of them to S3? (we're using Dio as our HttpClient)

Please help us to solve this problem.

Comment: what about creating zip(Compressed) file and uploading to S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1):

Try with AWS Amplify SDK
https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/flutter/

You should be able to use standard Amplify Storage Library
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/

Multipart uploads should be handled by Storage library.

Answer (score 1):

You might simply use some packages to upload files to S3 Bucket.

Simple file uploading -> amazon_s3_cognito: https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_s3_cognito

Some extra features -> minio: https://pub.dev/packages/minio